# ShinyApps can't find flexdashboard ui

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm using flexdashboard, so the ui file must be an rmd, "ui.rmd"

However, when I publish to shinyapps, I get the "no ui found error"

> No UI defined Shiny couldn't find any UI for this application. We
> looked in:
>
> www/index.html
>
> ui.R
>
> app.R

How does one publish a flexdashboard rmd?

Comment: Can you provide your code? (Or at least a small reproducible portion of it.)

Answer (score 0):

I had to rename "server.R" to anything else. Strange.